# Firefox icon remains in the Dock after quitting

Tags: dock, icon, firefox

Firefox icon remains in the Dock after I quit the application (CMD-Q and File > Quit alike).

I have unchecked "Show recent apps in Dock" in System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar.

Is there a way to fix/prevent this?

[image: screenshot of icon in dock and dock preferences]

Comment: With **Firefox** closed, remove the icon from the **Dock**, _right-click_ > **Options** > **Remove from Dock** or _click-hold_ and _drag_ it off, and it shouldn't stay the next time you quit **Firefox**

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but FF was in the dock again after restarting and quitting. I tried unchecking "keep in dock" while FF was still running and that seems to have done the trick. I saw your edits by the way, will make sure to get the capitals right next time.

Comment: nope, it's back in the Dock again. I'm going to try and find out whether CleanMyMac has anything to do with it....

Answer (score 3):

Right click the icon in the Dock > Options

If it's running you'll see "Keep in Dock" which you need to *uncheck*
if it's not running, instead you'll see "Remove from Dock"

Both do the same thing, remove it from the Dock when it's not running.

[image]

[image]

The third method is to grab the icon in the Dock & drag it out into an empty area of your desktop, then release…

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried "remove from dock" numerous times but no dice. After reading your answer I tried unchecking "keep in dock" while FF was still running and that seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Note that if you move the icon while the application is running, it will turn that back on and start keeping the icon in the dock again.

Comment: ....and it's back again. I run CleanMyMac every now and then, could that be causing the problem? I'll try and find out, will report back